# network from vmware win 8 - parent osx

Tags: vmware, home-networking

I am on OS X 10.8.5 running VMware 5.0.1 with a Windows 8 machine. I can't seem to network my Windows 8 machine to other windows machines.

I am however able to connect to the internet.

I am only running 1 VM machine, the other Windows laptops I am trying to connect to are physical devices. These are my options from VMware.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the network adapter mode on your windows VMs to Bridged Networking: Autodetect.

This will give your VM an IP address on your main network, rather than just accepting some traffic via your mac's IP.

Comment: i did this but then when i go back to OSX the wifi cant seem to connect

Comment: This setting would not affect your ability to connect to Wi-Fi networks, unless your VM has a DHCP server running on it. Try enableing this setting with the VM shut down, and see if you still cannot access Wireless networks.